# Spring WS Endpoint extract SOAP info

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

After reading doc on the Spring web site, still confused about how to extract information from a SOAP request.
For example, the SOAP request sent to server is like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:user="http://www.mysite.com/user/schemas">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <user:UserRequest>
         <!--You may enter the following 4 items in any order-->
         <user:Key>key</user:Key>
         <user:UserName>username</user:UserName>
         <user:RequesterName>reqname</user:RequesterName>
         <user:RequesterPassword>repw</user:RequesterPassword>
      </user:UserRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

On my server side I create an Endpoint like:

```
@Endpoint
public class UserEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.mysite.com/user/schemas";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "UserRequest")
    public void handleGetUserRequest() {
//Extract here...
    }   
}
```

How should I write extraction code here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at the [Spring WS samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples) for code ideas, depending on what else you are using in your application. For example: the HolidayEndpoint [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples/blob/master/tutorial/src/main/java/com/mycompany/hr/ws/HolidayEndpoint.java).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Endpoint("myEndpoint")
public class MyEndpoint {

    /**
     * Spring-WS Endpoint 
     * @param submitSomethingRequest 
     * @param header
     * @return SubmitSomethingResponse
     */
    @PayloadRoot(namespace="http://my.namespace.org/spec/1.0.1", localPart="submitSomethingRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public SubmitSomethingResponse submitSomethingRequest(@RequestPayload SubmitSomethingRequest submitSomethingRequest, **SoapHeader header**) {
        LOG.info("Received SOAP HEADER: " + header);
        if(header != null) {
            Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> hdrs = header.examineAllHeaderElements();
            while(hdrs.hasNext()) {
                SoapHeaderElement hdrEle = hdrs.next();
                System.out.prinltn(hdrEle.getName().getPrefix() + ":" + hdrEle.getName().getLocalPart());
                 ... //Do something here to parse DOM and extract headers you care about
            }
        }
...
```